# Failed to notify project evaluation listener error on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have the problem when syncing the build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
   id("com.android.application")
   id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
   id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
   id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.contactapp"
    compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.contactapp"
    minSdk = 21
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
}

dependencies {

val room_version = "2.6.1"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version")

implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version")

implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")

testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")

implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")


implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

It said "org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener."

I'm using Gradle 8.2 for this project, I tried to use "classpath" to change the version but the project didn't even understand that keyword to change the Gradle version.